# How can I exchange rows in Word for all tables?

Tags: vba, ms-word, copy, rows

I have 290 tables which have 14 rows for every table. I want to move row 12 to below row 13. Do you have any idea with macros?

I tried copy it and delete duplicate ones, it works but I need it for 290 tables so I need a loop in VBA.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    tbl.Rows(12).Range.Copy
    tbl.Rows(14).Range.Paste
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not done <s>a lot</s> any work in Word in ages, but give this a shot

```
Sub Sample() 

  Dim tbl As Table

  For Each tbl in ActiveDocument.tables
    tbl.Rows(12).Range.Copy
    tbl.Rows(14).Range.Paste
  Next

End Sub
```